# Nest multiple yield functions without eval

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, yield

I have the following structure (which might need a rework but to me this feels natural):

```
def get(baseVar):
    if type(baseVar) == GeneratorType:
        yield from baseVar
    else:
        yield baseVar

def multiply(baseVar):
    if type(baseVar) == GeneratorType:
        for item in baseVar:
            yield item*2
    else:
        yield baseVar*2

funcs = {'get' : get, 'multiply' : multiply}
result = 10
for f in funcs:
    result = funcs[f](result)

print(list(result))
```

Another approach would be (but this isn't dynamic at all) that performance wise works like i want it to, where an iterator object is passed to each functions thus gaining more momentum (theoretically) out of the functions:

```
for result in multiply(get(10)):
    ...
```

How can i nest multiple yield functions in a row and pass the generator object without hard-coding the function names, `getattr`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, what you want to do. If you have different functions, that work on single elements, use map:

```
def get(x):
    return x

def multiply(x):
    return x*2

print(list(map(multiply,map(get,[10]))
```

How would you like to get the names of you function? From external source, then your dict is the correct way, from internal, then you can use the functions directly:

```
funcs = (get, multiply)
result = [10]
for f in funcs:
    result = map(funcs,result)
```

Comment: On your last example, why are you looping over the `tuple` object when you're inserting the same `tuple` into map? Also will map join the iterating functions into one yield chain instead of looping over them one by one before passing the end result to `list()`?